# How to embed Adobe Acrobat Professional or Standard (NOT Reader) in my Application?

Tags: activex, adobe, acrobat

How to embed Adobe Acrobat Professional or Standard (NOT Reader) in my Application?

Does it has an ActiveX?

Answer (score 0):

No, these are full-scale applications. There is no way to embed these. However, what you can use is a PDF library (to manipulate PDFs). Adobe does provide one PDFL (it is paid).

Answer (score 0):

Although Acrobat cannot be "embedded" in your application, its automation type library does allow you to arrange that a .PDF is drawn in a window of your application using its `OpenInWindowEx()` routine.  This does not surface Acrobat's UI in your application, but you can incorporate quite a lot of its UI functionality by calls into the objects defined in the type library.